# Get-Random returning exclusively the minimum value

Tags: powershell, random, minimum

I've been trying to get Get-Random to choose between 0 and 1 so I can emulate the equivalent of a coin flip, but even when I place it in an infinite while loop it exclusively returns 0, Example code:

```
$test = Get-Random -Maximum 1 -Minimum 0
Write-Host $test
```

Only difference to my script is that this is in a function and it's being called in an infinite while loop, although even cutting out the middleman of the function doesn't work so it's definitely something wrong with my Get-Random. Hope that helps, and to keep in mind I'm still learning this stuff haha.

Comment: If you want `Get-Random` to pick one of some given options you can use the options as input like this `0,1 | Get-Random`. Because of the limited number of options you will likely have cases where you get a lot of the same output in a row.

Comment: I'll try that, however I've let my code run for a good 10 seconds before looking at the result, and 1 wasn't produced once, so let's pray this fixes it haha

Comment: Quote: [`-maximum` "Specifies a maximum value for the random number. `Get-Random` returns a value that is less than the maximum (**not equal**). Enter an integer, a double-precision floating-point number, or an object that can be converted to an integer or double, such as a numeric string (`"100"`).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random)

Comment: It worked, thanks again Olaf, and sorry for the simple question, still learning over here haha

Comment: An alternative for a coin-flip could also be `(Get-Date).Ticks -band 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Random -Maximum 1 -Minimum 0
```

returns a random integer greater than or equal to 0 and **less than** 1, so it will always return 0.

So, to get 0 or 1, the maximum would need to be 2

```
Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 2
```

Alternatively, specify or pipe an array of alternatives to be randomly selected from

```
Get-Random 0,1
0,1 | Get-Random
```